# React <video> tag wont play after yarn build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So I have a problem where video wont auto-play after building the project, although everything works fine when I run `yarn start` the video plays as expected.
But when running the built project error occurs in every browser it doesn't matter if its chrome/safari/firefox or anything else.

Note: I created the app via `npx create-react-app`

I even tried importing the video as follows (although I tried web-link too) and passing it to the src property

```
import video_mp4 from './assets/bg.mp4';
```

Also I saw that muted doesn't work well in React so I tried injection html via dangerouslySetInnerHTML like this

```
  var EmbedVideo = () => {
return (
  <div
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: `
     <video
       loop
       muted
       autoplay
       playsinline
       src="${video_mp4}"
       class="video_bg"
     />,
   `,
    }}
  />
);
```

};

and then

```
<div className='video_container'>
      <EmbedVideo />
    </div>
```

the correct way of doing stuff doesn't work either..

```
    <div className='video_container'>
      <video
        preload='auto'
        autoPlay
        muted
        loop
        playsInline
        className='video_bg'
      >
        <source src='/assets/bg.mp4' type='video/mp4' />
        <source src='/assets/bg.webm' type='video/webm' />
        <span>Your browser doesn't support mp4/webm formats :(</span>
      </video>
    </div>
```

Videos exist 100% after building the project.